# Javascript uppercase not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change text input value after user fill it, to uppercase string:

```
$('#University').blur(function(){
    if ( $(this).attr("value") != '') {
        var uni = $(this).val();
        uni.toUpperCase();
        alert(uni);
        $(this).attr("value", uni);
        };
});

<input type="text" name="Universidad" size="45" class="required" id="University">
```

If I write "leandro" into the field, the `alert(uni)` throws: "leandro" and not "LEANDRO". Any idea?

**I could not use CSS because I must send uppercase data through this form, and css only change the rendering and not the value**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change to this:

```
uni = uni.toUpperCase();
```

Strings are immutable, so you need to assign the result to the variable, overwriting the old string.

Comment: Good answer. And your username/avatar had me laughing for about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

The `.toUpperCase()` function returns a new string; it doesn't modify the existing string.

Comment: A good answer should explain the problem and (within reason) provide the modified, fixed code.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your function in a better way. See below,

```
$('#University').blur(function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`toUpperCase()` is a method.  It returns a value that you need to do something with.

You called the `.toUpperCase()` method on `uni`, but you didn't assign it anywhere.

```
uni = uni.toUpperCase();
```

... should help.